# Hyphonopoly writes error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: javascript

I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
at Hyphenopoly.js:153:11
at Hyphenopoly.js:209:7
at Hyphenopoly.js:933:3
```

This is my code:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  
  Hyphenopoly.addPattern('en', {
   
    "async": true,
    "path": *my link*
  });
  Hyphenopoly.config({

  }).then(() => {

    const messagesContainer = document.getElementById('messages_container'); 
    const text = messagesContainer ? messagesContainer.innerText : ''; 
    console.log(text);
    const hyphenatedText = Hyphenopoly.hyphenateText(text);
    console.log(hyphenatedText);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
});
```

I checked my links, errors in files (didn't find anything). I want Hophenopoly to control text wrapping in a specific block (messages_container), but instead I have this error.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out code until you stopped getting the error to verify what was the last code that was causing the error?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried it and it turned out that the problem is not in the code. This error came before it.